# Xamarin - on specific PC ResourceManager.GetString() always returns string for default cultureInfo

Tags: c#, xamarin

In my Xamarin App I use two .resx files as translations: **Translation.resx** for Polish (default) and **Translation.en.resx** for English.

UICulture switching is implemented and works great on multiple PC's android emulators, but we have one PC on which it does not work as expected.

For this specific PC, when `cultureInfo = {en}`, calling the `ResourceManager.GetString(text, cultureInfo);` ALWAYS returns translation string from default resource (from **Translation.resx**) instead of **Translation.en.resx**.

All PC's are using Win10, VS2019, the same versions of Xamarin SDK and Android Emulator, running code is from the same repository - everything is the same and still, on one computer it does not work as expected.

Can you please give me some hints where to look for the problem solution, what to check etc?

Comment: How are you checking the cultureInfo setting?

Comment: If you are returning an HTTP put the language in the header : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Language

Comment: UWP or Android?

Comment: @Jason - android

Comment: are you sure the Android emulator on this specific machine is configured identically to the others?

Comment: @Neil we have UICultureProvider implemented which sets the current cultureInfo as selected by the user via UI. We checked that actual cultureInfo value being set in debug, and it is set correctly just before call to `ResourceManager.GetString(text, cultureInfo)`, unfortunatelly, on one PC ResurceManager returns string from wrong .resx

Comment: @Jason - I watched thru android emulator settings and didnt find any differences, what should I look for exactly?

Comment: the device itself could be set for a different locale or language - you should be able to copy the emulator image from a working PC to the non-working one to test this theory.  Or you could try factory resetting the emulator image

Comment: @Jason - i tried multiple things - added the android emulator device exactly the same way as on the working PC, also tried to change android's system language etc. Everything looks the same between working and non-working PC, there must be some slight difference, but I can't find it. Language / globalisation setting in Windows itself should have no impact here, right?

Comment: I'm confused, is this a mobile device or a PC?  You keep mentioning PC, but then an Android emulator.

Comment: @Neil Android Emulator on PC in Visual Studio. Have several PCs, the same git repository, the same operating systems, the same versions of VS and Xamarin SDK, the same versions of Android Emulator. On all PCs except one - everything works.

Comment: The emulator should run entirely separately from the PC.  Is each emulator running exactly the same VM on each PC, or are there different versions of Android and screen sizes etc?

Comment: Yes, everything is the same, versions etc. It looks like I found the solution - I managed to fix the issue on that PC - I had to reinstall xamarin sdk and Android Emulator, add new emulator device and - to be sure - pull git repository fresh.
Still, I have no clue what was the issue, maybe xamarin/vs junk/temp/cache stuff did that (AppData stuff etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed issue with the PC, I had to:

- reinstall Xamarin SDK and Android Emulator (versions didn't change)
- add completely new emulator device in VS (default settings)
- pull fresh git repository to new location - even though there were no changes in code at all.

Comment: You can mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).